# iOS: NSFetchedResultsController, ControllerDidChangeContent executed twice after reordering

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Have started before a similar thread, but I now know where the problem lies, so I'm narrowing it down for you:

I have two view controllers. First one is called `MainCategoriesViewController`, 2nd one is `NetIncomeViewController`. Both are child of my `CoreDataViewController`. In the `CoreDataViewController` I basically just have implemented all delegate methods of the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate class with a property which is set if user changes occur (like reordering) and the controller shouldn't track these changes.

Ok my `MainCategoriesViewController` fetch request is setup like this and called from `viewDidLoad:`

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    self.managedObjectContext = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MainCategory"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                       managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:nil                                                                                  cacheName:@"MainCategoryCache"];
}
```

The reordering is done like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
{
    if (self.activeField && [self.activeField isFirstResponder]){
        [self.activeField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = YES;

    //Makes only a mutable copy of the array, but NOT the objects (references) within
    NSMutableArray *fetchedResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

    // Grab the item we're moving
    NSManagedObject *resultToMove = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

    // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
    [fetchedResults removeObject:resultToMove];
    // Now re-insert it at the destination.
    [fetchedResults insertObject:resultToMove atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];

    // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
    // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.
    int i = 1;
    for (MainCategory *fetchedResult in fetchedResults)
    {
        fetchedResult.position = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i++];
    }

    self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = NO;
}
```

Now the reordering is very fast. However if you switch for the first time to the `NetIncomeViewController` (doing the EXACT same fetch, however with a different cache name) the reordering in the `MainCategoriesViewControlle`r gets slow. I've tracked it down and I know now why. Because after `self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext` is set to NO, all `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods are executed TWICE! The first time they are as fast as before visiting the `NetIncomeViewController` for the first time, and the 2nd one is very slow.

Why is this now executed twice? Because they fetch from the same entity? Why does this even have an effect? And what can I do against it?

Answer (score 2):

(Same Answer from your other question)

Are you running the time profiler in Instruments?  If so, that will tell you why it is slow.  Time Profiler is your friend.

Second, put a break point in the delegate methods.  Look at the stack trace, that will show you what is causing things to fire.

Having said that, you are mutating the objects in your `NSFetchedResultsController` while you are in a callback method of the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

**That is bad.**

The `NSFetchedResultsController` is sensitive to changes in the data.  It doesn't care **what** you change only that you did change something.  As soon as you change something, it fires the delegate methods to notify you of the change.

If you change an object that the `NSFetchedResultsController` is watching while in the delegate you could easily get into an endless loop.  The only reason it is *only* firing twice is that on your second run through, you are setting the order to what it already was.

I would suggest moving your reordering logic to the `-[UITableViewDataSource tableView: moveRowAtIndexPath: toIndexPath:]` method.

Comment: HI Thx again for your answer. I'm very sorry but I don't really understand...I'm using the time profiler and of course the first time it's faster than the 2nd time. If I make a test the first time it takes 0.05 seconds. After visiting NetIncomeViewController (and basically having the same fetch request), the reordering takes 1. time again 0.05s, then 1.5s. What are you saying is bad that I do? Sorry I'm still new to iOS and struggling a little bit. Especially with the fact that my 2nd view controller is influencing my other VC's FetchedResultsController and I don't know why..

Comment: And if I'm looking at the stack trace, both times this delegate method is called by _managedObjectContextDidChange, UIApplicationMain and before that main. Don't know what to do with this info..

Comment: You are modifying a managed object in the delegate method of the NSFetchedResultsController. Don't do that, it is causing your problem.

Comment: Yeah but how would you do otherwise do a reorder in a NSFetchedResultsController? Or am I misunderstanding something? But the strange thing is nevertheless that before I create the 2nd NSFetchedResultsController everything works as it should

Comment: As I stated in my answer, do your reordering in the UITableViewDataSource method.

Answer (score 1):

Have to answer now my own question. Got it working with two edits:

1) (As flexaddicted suggested) Change the reorder like this in order that now other delegate methods are triggered:

```
int i = 1;
for (MainCategory *fetchedResult in fetchedResults)
{
    [fetchedResult setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"position"];
}
```

and make sure my managedObjectContext knows of this:

```
    // Save
    [((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) saveContext];
    // re-do the fetch so that the underlying cache of objects will be sorted
    // correctly
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
```

2) In my second view controller (which has the absolutely same fetch request as MainCategoriesViewController), I removed all delegate methods and redo the fetch each time I the view is displayed (in viewWillAppear).