# NSFetchedResultsControllers in different view controllers updating each other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Ok I get more and more general with this question, since I've noticed several lags in my app due to this. I've noticed the problem with reordering, but it happens in other places as well. I have a CoreDataViewController class which all my table view controllers subclass. And in this class I basically have all NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods as they are in the apple docs.

Then I've tried to find out how often changes are noticed by this NSFetchedResultsController to find out where my time lag is:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if(self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext) return;
    NSLog(@"ControllerDidChangeContent");
    TICK;
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    TOCK;
}
```

So for example in my view controller A, I have this fetch request (called from viewDidLoad):

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    //NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SpendingCategory"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES]];
    //[self.mainCategory.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsToMainCategory = %@", self.mainCategory];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                       managedObjectContext:self.mainCategory.managedObjectContext
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
}
```

If I change attributes for my objects in this view controller, my log prints out only once the comment "ControllerDidChangeContent" as it should. And is as fast as expected. And I mean really only a simple attribute change, just changing some number or string etc. such as:

```
spendingCategory.name = @"Hello world";
```

If however I've already accessed another view controller which setups its NSFetchedResultsController as well in viewDidLoad, my log is printed out twice. Here is the second NSFetchedResultsController:

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    self.managedObjectContext = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SpendingCategory"];

    NSSortDescriptor *mainCatPosition = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"belongsToMainCategory.position" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *spendingCatPosition = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES];

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mainCatPosition,spendingCatPosition,nil];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"liveBudget = %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                       managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"belongsToMainCategory.position"
                                                                                  cacheName:@"LiveBudget"];

}
```

My before mentioned simple attribute change takes way longer. And that's because now my log prints out twice (!) ControllerDidChangeContent. The first TICK-TOCK is still as fast as before, but the second takes over one second. And I guess this is because I have two NSFetchedResultsController watching the same entity.

1. Question:
   I still don't quite understand why they influence each other? I mean ok I update an attribute in one view controller so the other one should of course notice this change, but why are two didChangeContent triggered?
2. Question:
   How can I avoid that? Or how can I improve that?

Comment: Each VC receives one callback? Or one receives duplicate callbacks? What do the table view cells contain? Where are you setting the delegate at?

Comment: Each VC receives two callbacks after they have setup their FRC in their view did load. Table view cells containt just all their attributes (3 NSNumbers, 2 Strings). And delegate is set in view did load as well

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is better to check why the 1[sec] halt before turning to this solution.
myself, I have not experienced that delay when using multiple FRC's on the same context so my guess is the problem lie elsewhere.

as for your questions:

1. The FRC is listening for 'NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDid**Change**Notification' so all FRC's  listening on the same context on the same objects will trigger their delegate's methods when these objects are changed. Hence, it is clear why your log is printed twice (2 different FRC's changed their content)
2. 1[sec] is a long time for blocking the main thread and should be addressed (check with instruments what can be done). As I mentioned, there is no way to avoid that when using FRC's on the same context, but you can create a child context for each VC you stem an make the FRC listen to that child context only, then changes will only be visible to other FRC when you save down the context chain. as long as your VC stack is not very deep this should not be a real problem. In any case you want your other VC's to get updated with changes as they update the tableview to give a smooth user experience, so if the update take too long you should see why.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If I create a child context and save it, my other context then sees the changes even though the fetch isn't executed again? So I could make a child context in VC 1 change everything, save the context and the VC 2 immediately shows the changes? After checking it again, this problem really mainly arises with reordering, where I change attributes myself and stop the FRC checking for changes until I'm finished. And after changing everything I save the context and allow him to listen again. ([fetchedResult setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"position"];)

Comment: @MichiZH A save of a child context propagate the changes to the parent context, this in turn translates to changes in the parent context and the FRC listening to the parent context will not need to refetch the objects (execute a fetch). if your setup is VC1(parent)->VC2(child) and you make changes in child, when you save the child context the parent context will get the changes and update VC1. changing objects inside FRC delegate methods is problematic as changes will invoke these methods again on the next runloop.

Comment: Well no I'm changing the ordering in the table delegate method and just stop the fetched results Controller from listening. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935311/ios-nsfetchedresultscontroller-controllerdidchangecontent-executed-twice-after. And yes, there are of course multiple objects changed, but that the controller has changed is sent twice, for bot FRC listening. And this takes time. I'm thinking about implementing the parent-child relationsship.

Comment: I've solved it in another case like this: Since one of the two view controllers with the same fetch is just for display and the other mainly for edit, I've just removed all delegate methods in the display view controller and just do always a new fetch in viewWillAppear. So far I don't have performance problems with this solution. Or is this a bad solution?

Comment: Your reordering method is very inefficient, faulting objects one by one (very slow on the first run). second, you ignored Marcus S. Zarra's recommendation on updating objects in your FRC delegate methods. your setup seems complex. performing a fetch and rebuilding the table view on each `viewWillAppear` might also be complex and inefficient.

Comment: Also, you don't stop your FRC from invoking its delegate methods, only setting a flag to ignore them. they will still be called for each object changed (that is part of the FRC request).