# UITableView endUpdates taking more than a second on NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a `UITableView` based on the Xcode Master/Detail template using CoreData. When a property of the the `NSManagedObject` is changed in the `detailViewController`, the call to
 `[self.tableView endUpdates]` takes more than a second. The table has about 30 entries.

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"endUpdates start");
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    NSLog(@"endUpdates end");
}
```

This is the log output, the Type 4 is the `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`. Only one row is updated.

```
2014-01-25 12:40:31.313 Batteries[1511:60b] beginUpdates
2014-01-25 12:40:31.315 Batteries[1511:60b] Type: 4
2014-01-25 12:40:31.317 Batteries[1511:60b] endUpdates start
2014-01-25 12:40:32.344 Batteries[1511:60b] endUpdates end
```

With inserts and deletions, the `endUpdates` method invocation is quick:

```
2014-01-25 12:39:46.732 Batteries[1511:60b] beginUpdates
2014-01-25 12:39:46.733 Batteries[1511:60b] Type: 2
2014-01-25 12:39:46.735 Batteries[1511:60b] endUpdates start
2014-01-25 12:39:46.742 Batteries[1511:60b] endUpdates end
```

If I replace the `beginUpdates - endUpdates`sequence with `[self.tableView reloadData]`, it is much quicker:

```
2014-01-25 13:02:32.028 Batteries[1522:60b] Type: 4
2014-01-25 13:02:32.032 Batteries[1522:60b] reload start
2014-01-25 13:02:32.034 Batteries[1522:60b] reload end
```

As requested here is the `NSFetchedResultsController` Code:
    #pragma mark - Fetched results controller

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Battery" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // sort by identifier ASC
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"identifier" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}    

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"beginUpdates");
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    NSLog(@"Type: %u", type);
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            self.insertedIndexPath = newIndexPath;
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"endUpdates start");
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
//    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"endUpdates end");
    if (self.insertedIndexPath) {
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.insertedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
        self.insertedIndexPath = nil;
    }

}

/*
// Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed.

 - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
 */

- (void)configureCell:(BatteryCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.identifierLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"identifier"];
    cell.manufacturerLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"manufacturedBy"] manufacturerName];

}
```

Does anyone have an idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: have you read [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940047/nsfetchedresultscontrollers-in-different-view-controllers-updating-each-other/20943236#20943236)

Comment: Just now. I only have one NSFetchedResultsController and my controllerDidChangeContent is only called once. Interesting that endUpdates is taking a second on the second call though.

Comment: The question is: are you modifying your objects in one of the FRC delegate methods?

Comment: No, I am not modifying NSManagedObjects in one of the FRC delegate methods.

Comment: I suggest you share your update code and FRC delegate methods (including the FRC setup), also describe any background operations and CoreData stack structure. You can also use "Instruments" and see what is hanging your main thread ...

Comment: I used the Instruments Time Profiler to determine that it spent roughly a second in `[self.tableView endUpdates]`. Then I bracketed the statement with NSLog statements as shown above. The actual endUpdates method invocation takes a second to return. I use only one thread.

Comment: What is the "drill down" of your profiling? what actually took that long?

Comment: I found it. It is animating the changes even when the view is not visible. That is what takes the time.